# class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class : use @query to get records from two diffrent tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I need to get a custom json containing the fields of the class **Utilisateur** plus a fied (centre_rc) of another class **Operateur**
I tried ti implement this using @Transient with centre_rc in Utilisateur.java but my json is always null. Now i tried to get Object[] in UtilisateurRepository.java (the code is shown below) but I get this error `class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Utilisateur (java.math.BigInteger is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Utilisateur is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @51ff3ed4)`

here is **Utilisateur** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utilisateur")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nom_utilisateur")
    private String nomUtilisateur;

    @Column(name = "prenom")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "date_inscription")
    private LocalDate dateInscription;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    /*
    @Transient
    @JsonSerialize
    private String centre_rc;
    */

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "utilisateurs" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Operateur operateur;

    //getters & setters
}
```

here is **Operateur** class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "operateur")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Operateur implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "centre_rc")
    private String centreRc;

    @Column(name = "numero_rc")
    private String numeroRc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operateur")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "operateur" }, allowSetters = true)
    private Set<Utilisateur> utilisateurs = new HashSet<>();
    //getters & setters
}
```

In UtilisateurRepository.java here is my SQL query:

```
@Query(value = "select u.*, o.centre_rc from utilisateur u inner join operateur o on o.id=u.operateur_id", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Object[]> findAllOperateurs(Pageable pageable);
```

In UtilisateurResource.java

```
 @GetMapping("/utilisateursOperateurs")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Object[]>> getAllUtilisateursCalledOperateurs(
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Utilisateurs Operateurs");
        Page<Object[]> page = utilisateurRepository.findAllOperateurs(pageable);
        for(Object[] obj : page){
            Utilisateur utilisateur = (Utilisateur) obj[0];
            String centre_rc = (String) obj[1];
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I tried @Transient field called centre_rc in Utilisateur class but the json return null for this field

Comment: I don't think that query would find out on its own that the first few fields could be packed into an `Utilisateur` object. Instead you probably have a number (`obj[0]`, `BigInteger` as the message says, which is probably `u.id`) and 3 strings (`obj[1]` is probably `u.centre_rc`, then `obj[2]` is probably `u.numero_rc`, and `obj[3]` may be `o.centre_rc`).

Comment: @tevemadar yeah I got it, please any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: I think you need to `select u, o.centre_rc` to get the Utilisateur-Object as first element in the array

Comment: @Turo it gives me this error `could not prepare statement; SQL [select u, o.centre_rc from utilisateur u inner join operateur o on o.id=u.operateur_id limit ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late reply, didn't see the native query=true. Has to be a JPA Query with Cclass name and membe name...

Answer (score 1):

`findAllOperateurs` doesn't return an array with first object is a Utilisateur and second object is a String like that.

When you run this query directly in DB, each row it returns is an element in the `page` array.

By accessing `obj[0]`, you're accessing the first column of the row which is the id of type BigInteger, you can't cast a BigInteger to Utilisateur.

You can cast `obj` Utilisateur.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Please any suggestion to implement what I want ?